# How to get user accesses token Facebook to get user id

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, sdk

i'm trying to get user access token i tried a million time but is not working can any one please help i'm trying like this

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '************************',
    'app_secret' => '********************',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
]);

try {
    // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{ THE ACCESS TOKEN }');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

return $user;
```

i try to log in like this

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['public_profile','email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://WebSite', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';

  try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        var_dump($accessToken);
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if (!isset($accessToken)) {
        if ($helper->getError()) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
            echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
            echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
            echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
        } else {
            header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
            echo 'Bad request';
        }
        exit;
    }

// Logged in
    echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
    var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
    $tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
    echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
    var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
    $tokenMetadata->validateAppId($config['1611286245754691']);
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
    $tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

    if (!$accessToken->isLongLived()) {
        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        try {
            $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
            exit;
        }

        echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
        var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
    }

    $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string)$accessToken;
```

after i login the returned `url` is like this

```
http://websitr?code=*******&state=********#_=_
```

and return error

```
Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.
```

i don't relay know what is the code and state in the returned `url` my code from the [face book documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0)

please any help to get the face book user id and the accesses token many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get your access token, just :

```
    // The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    // Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
    $tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
    print_r($tokenMetadata->getUserId());
```

Comment: It's help for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i manage to work this first i add this function to get the face book log in link

```
function Get_FaceBookProfileLink() // get the face book link
{
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '********',
        'app_secret' => '*******',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['public_profile','email']; // Optional permissions
    $RedirectURL = home_url() .'/user-profile/'. wp_get_current_user()-> ID;
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(  $RedirectURL , $permissions);

    return $loginUrl;
}
```

in my page that i want to get the user id if call this function and hide the face book link because i want trigger this link on `checkbox` input click

```
$FaceBookProfileLink = Get_FaceBookProfileLink();

 <?php echo '<a id="FaceBookProfileLink" href="' . $FaceBookProfileLink . '" style="display: none;" >Log in with Facebook!</a>'; ?>


 $("#facebook").click(function () {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

                window.location.href =$('#FaceBookProfileLink').attr('href');

            } else if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: ajaxurl,

                    data: ({
                        type: "POST",
                        action: 'Ajax_DisableFaceBookLink'
                    }),
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.Message === 'Updated') {
                            alert('FaceBook disabled');
                        } else {
                            alert('ERRORS');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

after the click on the `checkbox` input click it will trigger the Facebook login event and will generate a code and states in the URL the returend url used to be exchange with an accesses token so after the reloading i toke the code from the URL like this in the same page that i want to get the user id

```
 $parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        parse_str($parts['query'], $query);

        if(!empty($query['code'])) {

            $IsFaceBookLinked = LinkFaceBookToUserProfile($query['code']);

        }
```

then the process of getting the user id is in  `LinkFaceBookToUserProfile()` function like this

```
function Get_FaceBookAccessToken($code)
{
    $AppSecret = '***************';
    $APPID = '******************';
    $RedirectURL = home_url() .'/user-profile/'. wp_get_current_user()-> ID;
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$APPID.'&redirect_uri='.$RedirectURL.'&client_secret='.$AppSecret.'&code='.$code;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $results = json_decode($result, true);

    return $results['access_token'];
}

function Get_FaceBookUser($AccessToken) {

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '*************',
        'app_secret' => '*******************',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
    ]);

    try {
        // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $AccessToken);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $user = $response->getGraphUser();

    return $user;
}

function Get_FaceBookUserID($code)
{
   return Get_FaceBookUser(Get_FaceBookAccessToken($code));
}

function LinkFaceBookToUserProfile($code)
{
    $FaceBookUserID = Get_FaceBookUserID($code)['id'];

    $UserPod = pods('user', wp_get_current_user()->ID);

    $data = array(
        'facebook_link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/' . $FaceBookUserID
    );
    $UserID = $UserPod->save($data);
    return $UserID;
}
```

hope to help any one looking for this and save time [link may help you](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4).